# Value can't be converted to integer while debugging with gdb

Tags: debugging, memory, gdb

I am trying to debug assembler code with gdb in ubuntu x64 command line.

A **disassemble** command shows the following

```
   0x0000000000401247 <+10>:    mov    %r12,-0x8(%rsp)
=> 0x000000000040124c <+15>:    sub    $0x18,%rsp
   0x0000000000401250 <+19>:    mov    %rdi,%rbx
```

and after **stepi** command I want to explore the memory with address **$0x18** to check the result of command.
I am using the following command **x $0x18** and getting error **Value can't be converted to integer.**

And after trying the command **x 0x18** it gives **Cannot access memory at address 0x18** error.

How can I check the result of command in memory with address 0x18?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to explore the memory with address $0x18

There *is no* memory at address `0x18`. The assembly instruction you are looking at: `sub $0x18,%rsp` subtracts a *constant* `0x18` from previous value of the RSP register (that's what `$` in front of `0x18` means).